# Bouncing balls in Android - onDraw() Android Studio shows memory usage continues growing

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, ondraw

I'm not sure why this is happening.  I'm not allocating anything during the onDraw (at least I don't think I am).

I don't want to overload you guys with code so I've just posted the onDraw.  I'll happily post more if requested.

This is problematic because the garbage collector will be triggered causing a quick pause. While the pause is not a huge deal (only I notice it so far) it's not clean and I don't like that memory usage growing.

When viewing the "Memory Monitor" in Android Studio, Allocated continues to grow by an average of .01 MB but it does so quickly.

Here is the onDraw method.  Note I'm not creating any paint objects inside of onDraw.

Anything jump out? Been spending some time on this and can't figure it out.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas cvs) {
    selectedCount = 0;
    if (Surplus_balls.size() > 0){
        for (calorie_crush_ball c : Surplus_balls) {
            c.bounce(cvs);

            xval = c.getX();
            yval = c.getY();

            cvs.drawCircle(xval, yval, c.getDIPRadius(), c.getPaint());
            cvs.drawCircle(xval, yval, c.getDIPRadius(), black_paint);

            if (c.getIsSelected()) {
                selectedCount = selectedCount + c.get_calorieValue();
                cvs.drawCircle(xval, yval, c.getDIPRadius(), c.getSelection_paint());
            }

            cvs.drawText(String.valueOf(c.get_calorieValue()),
                    xval - c.get_calorieValueXRenderOffset(getContext(), white_text_paint),
                    yval - white_text_paint_text_height + 2,
                    white_text_paint);

            if (c.get_calorieValue() == 1) {
                txtLeft = xval - word_calorie_width;
                cvs.drawText(calorie_text_singular, txtLeft, yval + white_text_paint_text_height / 2, small_white_text_paint);
            } else {
                txtLeft = xval - word_calories_width;
                cvs.drawText(calorie_text_plural, txtLeft, yval + white_text_paint_text_height / 2, small_white_text_paint);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (calorie_crush_ball c : Calorie_balls) {
            c.bounce(cvs);

            xval = c.getX();
            yval = c.getY();

            cvs.drawCircle(xval, yval, c.getDIPRadius(), c.getPaint());
            cvs.drawCircle(xval, yval, c.getDIPRadius(), black_paint);

            if (c.getIsSelected()) {
                selectedCount = selectedCount + c.get_calorieValue();
                cvs.drawCircle(xval, yval, c.getDIPRadius(), c.getSelection_paint());
            }
            txtTop = yval;

            cvs.drawText(String.valueOf(c.get_calorieValue()),
                    xval - c.get_calorieValueXRenderOffset(getContext(), white_text_paint),
                    yval - white_text_paint_text_height + 2,
                    white_text_paint);

            if (c.get_calorieValue() == 1) {
                cvs.drawText(calorie_text_singular, xval - word_calorie_width, txtTop + white_text_paint_text_height / 2, small_white_text_paint);
            } else {
                cvs.drawText(calorie_text_plural, xval - word_calories_width, txtTop + white_text_paint_text_height / 2, small_white_text_paint);
            }
        }

    }

    if (selectedCount > 0) {
        cvs.drawText(String.valueOf(String.valueOf(selectedCount) + " " + calorie_text_plural), 10, canvasCenterY, calories_paint);
    }

    h.postDelayed(runnable, FRAME_RATE);
}
```

Also here is the runnable that's used to trigger the onDraw() method:

private static class SafeRunnable implements Runnable {

```
private final WeakReference<calorie_crush_mainview> parentReference;

public SafeRunnable(calorie_crush_mainview parent) {
    parentReference = new WeakReference<calorie_crush_mainview>(parent);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (parentReference != null) {
        final calorie_crush_mainview parent = parentReference.get();
        if (parent != null) {
            runWithParent(parent);
        }
    }
}

public void runWithParent(calorie_crush_mainview parent) {
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not too up on Canvas and drawing, but you appear to be drawing new text every time. As there is no way to know that the string values are unchanged, perhaps you're seeing the effects of new string allocations.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment.  I gave that a shot but no luck.  It actually is happening on the very first drawCircle call I found after a bit of investigating

Comment: Actually...check that.  After commenting out the drawCircle...it's still happening.

I'll post back here as I slowly isolate the problem in the hopes that someone might help.

Comment: Your memory is growing with all the drawCircle and drawText calls commented out? If that's the case, seems the memory issue is elsewhere.

Comment: You can use the Allocation Tracker to see the last 512 allocations.  That should tell you what's being allocated.  See e.g. https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#TrackAllocations